# can you use data tables across multiple apps?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am attempting to build several apps for different use cases in our business. However many of them share data. Such as our Inventory app will use the same customer data as our field audit app, and many apps will need to access the dataset we made to hold SKU information.

As such, my question is, if app a, has a table with x information. can App b access the same table?

Comment: Are you using Google Drive table or SQL?

Comment: Google cloud sql

Answer (score 0):

It could.

You can add a model to an AppMaker App to get information from external sources.
See the information here:
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/overview

Comment: Great! Thanks for this! Now to clarify, how do I setup a custom SQL? I already setup the default one? By custom does it mean to setup another database or am I missing somthing?

Comment: Here are some options about getting access to another data source: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/external-data-options